# CSS - How to vertically align this div?

Tags: html, css

I'm not the best at CSS so my question might look stupid, sorry if it does :P
I am trying to vertically align the div so in the middle of the screen
here is my HTML:
http://pastebin.com/747imppN

This is my style sheet:
http://pastebin.com/Qgcx7dnb

Thanks for the help in advance guys!

Comment: Please put in your code...

Comment: First of all, like @TJonS said, please include your code in the post itself rather than linking to it. Secondly, which div? You have two divs in your HTML. Try reformatting your question to include the code and to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your .popup_box div's css:

```
.popup_box{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nHQjZ/)

Hope this helps. But please, put your code in your question. :)

Note: This will only work as long as you have fixed width to your element.